# Python with tkinter, problems with the line drawing between buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently learning Python and started using ktinter. My goal right now is to create a drag and drop function which creates buttons and connects them with a line.

This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
class Test:
def __init__(self, master):
    X1 = int(input())
    Y1 = int(input())
    X2 = int(input())
    Y2 = int(input())

    self.blackLine = Canvas.create_line(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)



    convas = Canvas(master)
    convas.pack()
    button1 = Button(text = "button 1")
    button1.configure(width = 0, activebackground = "#D2D2D2", relief = GROOVE)
    button1_window = convas.create_window(X1, Y1, anchor=NW, window=button1)
    button1.update()
    print (button1.winfo_geometry())

    button2 = Button(text = "button 2")
    button2.configure(width = 0, activebackground = "#D2D2D2", relief = GROOVE)
    button2_window = convas.create_window(X2, Y2, anchor=NW, window=button2)
    button2.update()
    print (button2.winfo_geometry())
```

Now as you can probably see I'm testing the the line drawing by inputing some values in the intergers at the beginning and than using them in the button1,2_window coordinates for the button placement on the canvas. Now whenI start the program my problem appears.

As soon as I have entered the 4 numbers like 4, 4, 10, 10 it gives me an AttribuiteError saying this:

"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_create'"

I'm not sure but I guess its somehow using the numbers as a string and therefore I tried it with the int(input)) instead of a normal input() function.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You line needs to be made using the canvas instance, not the Canvas class. To do that it must be moved after the Canvas initialization.

```
convas = Canvas(master)
convas.pack()

self.blackLine = convas.create_line(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
```